# How to generate (not scan) a UPC_A barcode from integer string using cordova phonegap barcodescanner

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I need to generate a UPC_A barcode as a picture in the item's description from the string contains a barcode itself

I've tried to use

```
cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.encode(
    cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.Encode.TEXT_TYPE, "1234567890123",
    function(success){}, function(fail){}, {'format': 'UPC_A'}
)
```

but without success, i'm still getting a qr-code in the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plugin does not generate barcodes but QTR, even though you can scan barcodes too.

You can maybe check out [this JS lib instead (JsBarcode)](https://github.com/lindell/JsBarcode) for barcodes only